# Passing parameters in a jQuery variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, parameters

I've been away from jQuery development and all js in general for about three years. I can not for the life of me remember how this is supposed to work. This has been going on for four days, and I could really use some help.
Can you tell me what I am doing wrong here:

```
var $imgAll = $(function(f, a) {
    '&lt;img src=&quot;' + f + ' alt=&quot' + a + '&quot;&gt;';
});

var $imgAC = $imgAll('filename1.jpg', 'Some Alt Text');
var $imgBC = $imgAll('filename2.jpg', 'Some Alt Text');

$page.append($imgAC);
```

I want an output of code for images whose filenames (f) and alt texts (a) are passed using a single function. It looks like Greek at this point because I'm staring at it constantly.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Not sure why you're wrapping this function inside `$`. If you want to just return image markup, just write a simple function and construct img tag inside with f and a...

Comment: var $imgAll = (f, a) => `<img src="${f}" alt="${a}"/>`

Comment: Definitely confusing use of `$` - `$` doesn't mean "function" - in a jquery context *some* people use $ to indicate a jquery *object*, eg `var $txt = $(".input")` as a convention, but you wouldn't use this on your functions - and none of your variables are jquery objects.  3 years ago probably wouldn't have been using arrow functions much, so your code would be:  `var imgAll = function(f,a) { return "<img src='" + f + "'..."; };` to return as an html `string`.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want `$imgAll` to be a function, not the return value of a call of `$`. Here is how it could work:

```js
var $imgAll = function(src, alt) {
    return $('<img>').attr({src, alt});
}

var $imgAC = $imgAll('https://stackoverflow.design/assets/img/logos/so/logo-stackoverflow.svg', 'Some Alt Text');

$("body").append($imgAC);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Note how the call to `attr` avoids building the attribute strings yourself, and thereby the potential problems with characters that need escaping. Also, by naming the function parameters as the attribute names (`src` and `alt`) you can use the short object literal notation. You could even use an arrow function expression:

```
const $imgAll = (src, alt) => $('<img>').attr({src, alt});
```

Comment: Could you give me some feed-back? Did this answer your question?